# camera orientation in android 2.3.6

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera

I am facing problem for displaying camera preview in android 2.3.6 device.I have used this code for changing camera orientation but for 2.3.6 it is not working and for other versions it is working properly.

[image: In device 2.2.1]

[image: In device 2.3.6]

First image in device 2.2.1,Second image in device 2.3.6.I want camera preview as same as in 2.2.1 for device 2.3.6.Below is my code

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8)
            {
         mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


       }
        else
        {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            {

               p.set("orientation", "portrait");
               p.set("rotation", 90);

            }
           if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {

                p.set("orientation", "landscape");
                p.set("rotation", 90);

            }
     }
```

And i have specified screen orientation portrait in manifest.Kindly suggest me a solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code:

```
private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    int result;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10){
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
        }

        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

    }else{
        if(cameraId==CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }else{
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get Camera Id using

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
private Camera openFrontFaceCamera() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
            try {
                mCameraId=camIdx;
                cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Custom Camera", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
private Camera openRearFaceCamera() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK  ) {
            try {
                mCameraId=camIdx;
                cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Custom Camera", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```